Issue with Draw.io Plugin: Database Datatypes Not Imported
I'm encountering an issue with the Drwaw.io plugin when using the "Insert - from SQL" feature. When I import the following code:
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);

All attributes are displayed, but their data types are not.

I've tried using both the desktop app and the online version, as I prefer not to upload my own ERD data to the cloud, but neither has worked for me.
Am I missing something here?
